# How can I make the efficent for loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops

I am writing the csv file in python and there are four levels of nested objects. like

I need to show the csv like this

`StudentName`, `StudentClass` `SubjectName` , `SubjectDate` `SubjectBookNAme` , `SubjectBookpage`

I am using loop like

`Just example not actual code`

```
for s in students:
    for subject in s.subjects:
         for book in subject.books :
          writer.writerow(s.name, s.class, subject.name, book.name)
```

This works fine if i have all child objects.

But when i have no books or subjects then loop does not work.

I don't want to use many `if else` is there any way to write those loops efficently that if there are no rows in for loop then system works

Comment: What doesn't work? Post your actual code.

Comment: How should it work when there are no subjects or books?

Comment: Is it *that* hard to keep some minimum standards of text formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `s.subjects` is `None` or some other `False` value when there are no subjects, and likewise for books

```
for s in students:
    for subject in s.subjects or []:
        for book in subject.books or []:
            writer.writerow(s.name, s.class, subject.name, book.name)
```

More generally, you can write

```
for s in students:
    for subject in s.subjects if <condition> else []:
        for book in subject.books if <condition> else []:
            writer.writerow(s.name, s.class, subject.name, book.name)
```

Where `<condition>` is whatever expression makes sense

Comment: i am trying this `for m,n in izip_longest(l1,l2,fillvalue=defaultdict()) or []` and its not working where l1 , l2 are lists. so i want that even if both are empty even then loop should run once

Comment: @user2294401, so your problem really has nothing to do with your question. izip_longest always returns a generator, so it's never `False`. Aside, using `fillvalue=defaultdict()` will use the same defaultdict for all the fillvalues which is probably not what you want!

Comment: @user2294401, So you want the loop to run once even if the lists are empty? What should it write out in that case?

Comment: i even tried the empty loop like `for m,n in []` my code after the loop is not running. is there any way that if loop is false even then code after that runs once. i mean then all the students info , becaus eno matter what strudent info will always be there and other column will be empty

Comment: @user2294401, I guess I don't understand how you are mapping the csv rows onto your objects. Can you add some details to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should Initialize `s.subjects` and `subject.books` with empty lists. That way you won't get an error when trying to iterate them here or on other places in your code.

Comment: if i do that then what will happen if i have the empty list

Comment: @user2294401 nothing will happen, the loop won't be entered... try it.

Comment: is there any way that even if the list is empty that loop run only once. All i want is that if there are no child elements then loop should behave like it don't exist and other code below that executes

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your student.subjects and subject.books with [], and then it'll work. Just as what @user714965 said.

or, use list-comprehension:

```
for s in [stu if stu.has_key(subjects) for stu in students]:
    for subject in [subj if subj.has_key(books) for subj in s.subjects]:
         lists= [(s.name, s.class, subject.name, book.name) for book in subject.books]
              print r'\n'.join(r','join(lists))
```

or

if your loop is not very deep,try something like this:

```
fn= s.has_key('subjects') and (lambda s: /do sth. with s/ ) or (lambda s: /do sth. else with s/)
```

in your loop, use the `fn` like this,

```
[fn(s) for s in students ]
```